# How to rewrite the SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Assume we have a process given by
$$
dY_t = - \frac{\beta^2}{2}dt + \beta dB_t 
$$
with $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ being an $\mathcal{F}_t$-Brownian motion.
We can rewrite the SDE in integral form as
$$
Y_t =y_0 - \int_0^t \frac{\beta^2}{2} dt + \beta \int_0^t dB_t, \quad x_0 \in \mathbb{R}
$$

If we use Itô's formula for the process $t\cdot Y_t$ we get that
$$
\begin{aligned}
t Y_t &= \int_0^t Y_s ds + \int_0^t s dY_s + [Y,t]_t \newline
&= \int_0^t Y_s ds - \frac{1}{2}\beta^2  \int_0^t s ds + \beta \int_0^t s dB_s
\end{aligned}
$$
And if we rewrite this we get the expression
$$
\int_0^t Y_s ds = t \cdot Y_t + \frac{1}{2}\beta^2 \int_0^t s ds - \beta\int_0^t s dB_s
$$
How can I rewrite the last part to get
$$
\int_t^T Y_s ds = Y_t (T-t) - \frac{1}{2}\beta^2 \int_t^T (T-s)  ds + \beta \int_t^T (T-s) dB_s
$$
I cannot understand how we would ever get a term with $(T-t)Y(t)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Hopefully the question is correct now.
We can rewrite and get
$$
\int_0^t Y_s ds = t Y_t + \frac{1}{2}\beta^2 \int_0^t (T-s) ds - \beta \int_0^t (T-s) dW_s 
$$
And for $T > t$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^T Y_s ds - \int_0^t Y_s ds &= \int_t^T Y_s ds \\
&= T Y_T - t Y_t + \frac{1}{2}\beta^2 \int_t^T (T-s) ds - \beta \int_t^T (T-s) dB_s
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: The correct expression for $tY_t$ should be \begin{aligned}
t Y_t 
&= \int_0^t Y_s\,ds {\color{red}{-}} \frac{1}{2}\beta^2  \int_0^t s\, ds + \beta \int_0^t{\color{red}{s}} \,dB_s
\end{aligned} What follows must therefore be wrong.

Comment: You're correct i did forget the s aswell as the bounds of integration.

Comment: And a minus sign in front of the $\frac12\beta^2$-term.

Comment: It should be corrected now.

Comment: No.  You mentioned the integration bounds.

Comment: Hard work. Now to the next equation. What a mess. I get $$\int_0^t Y_{\color{red}s}\,d{\color{red}s} = t \cdot Y_t + \frac{1}{2}\beta^{\color{red}2} \int_0^t {\color{red}s} \,d{\color{red}s} - \beta\int_0^t s dB_{\color{red}s}\,.$$

Comment: $\frac12\beta^{\color{red}2}$ please.

Comment: The left hand side looks still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you can rewrite the last part to get that last
equation.
From
$$\tag1
\int_0^t Y_s\,ds = tY_t + \frac{1}{2}\beta^2 \int_0^t s\, ds - \beta \int_0^t s\, dB_s
$$
I get
$$\tag2
\int_t^T Y_s\,ds = TY_T-tY_t + \frac{1}{2}\beta^2 \int_t^T s\, ds - \beta \int_t^T s\, dB_s\,.
$$
From
$$\tag3
Y_t=Y_0-\frac12\beta^2t+\beta B_t
$$
I get
\begin{align}\tag4
TY_T&=TY_0-\frac12\beta^2T^2+T\beta B_T\,,\\
tY_t&=tY_0-\frac12\beta^2t^2+t\beta B_t\,.\tag5
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\tag6
TY_T-tY_t&=Y_0(T-t)-\beta^2\int_t^Ts\,ds+\beta(TB_T-tB_t)
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}\tag7
\int_t^TY_s\,ds&=Y_0(T-t)-\frac12\beta^2\int_t^Ts\,ds+\beta(TB_T-tB_t)-\beta\int_t^Ts\,dB_s\\
&=Y_0(T-t)-\frac12\beta^2\int_t^Ts\,ds+\beta\int_0^T(T-s)\,dB_s-\beta\int_0^t(t-s)\,dB_s\,.\tag8
\end{align}